# Can I use libcurl 7.60.0 with CentOS 6.9?

Tags: linux, centos, https, curl

My production server is CentOS 6.9. 
Is libcurl 7.60.0 compatible for CentOS 6.9?
Where can I get more information on this?

Thanks.  Jessica

Answer (score 0):

Look for a package for your distribution family of choice, and most importantly maintained and updated. You take on that maintainer responsibility if you compile it yourself.

CentOS 8 has a libcurl that new. Upgrade to 8. Run applications that cannot be upgraded in CentOS 6 containers.

Comment: Thanks John.  These are production servers which need new curl but the OS cannot be upgraded.  Thus, it much remain on CentOS 6.9.

Comment: That is going to be a problem on November 30th, 2020 when updates for CentOS 6 stop. Creating security patches for an entire distro yourself is far more complicated than maintaining one package. Start the upgrade project now.